# How to trunk VLANs over Layer 3 EtherChannel?

Tags: cisco, vlan, cisco-catalyst, layer3, etherchannel

I am trying to setup a network that includes an EtherChannel link between two Cisco Layer 3 switches (Catalyst 3750). I am using a collapsed core hierarchical network.

[image: collapsed core topology]

The picture above is my topology. On my layer 2 access switches (S1, S2, S3) I have several hosts connected right now, on several VLANs.
My issue tho is that a host on for example S2, can't communicate with L3-1 through the EtherChannel between L3-1 and L3-2. I've tried making it a Layer 3 EtherChannel with IP's, and I can ping across, but it's like it wont propagate my tagged VLAN traffic.

**Example**:

> I connect HOST-A to L3-1 on interface GigabitEthernet2/0/1.
>
> I make GigabitEthernet2/0/1 switchport access on VLAN 20.
>
> HOST-B is connected to a switchport access VLAN 20 port on S2.
>
> HOST-B tries to ping L3-2. Succesful.
>
> HOST-B tries to ping across to L3-1 / HOST-A. Not succesful.

PS. I also have HSRP setup on the Layer 3 switches, for all my VLANs. Also I have a Main Windows Server 2016 Domain Controller connected to L3-1 and a Backup connected to L3-2.

Let me know if you need the IP scope.

I appreciate all help! I just want to know what I have to think of/be sure of is working, to make this network communicate. Any help that can guide me to what i can do to get traffic all the way to the WAN, and so that my hosts on S1, S2 and S3 can connect to the internet. Much appreciated.

**CONFIGURATION:**

```
L3-1

Port-Channel:

!
interface Port-channel1
 no switchport
 ip address 172.16.0.1 255.255.255.252
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/19
 no switchport
 no ip address
 channel-group 1 mode desirable
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/20
 no switchport
 no ip address
 channel-group 1 mode desirable
!
```

**L3-2 has same configuration on same ports and channel-group. It's IP address is 172.16.0.2 255.255.255.252 instead.**

VLAN-config:
[image: show vlan brief in cisco terminal]

All links between layer-3 and layer-2 switches are trunks. A snippet from L3-2:
[image: interface overview from layer 3 switch]

**S1**

VLAN-config:
[image: vlan overview on switch]

**S2**

VLAN-config:
[image: vlan overview on switch]

**S3**

VLAN-config:
[image: vlan overview on switch]

Comment: you need to add the configuration of the devices. Also the result of the `show vlan`command on S1, S2 & L3-1 along with the name of the interfaces that connect those switches together would be useful.

Comment: Definitely need configurations to give any help. Remember to sanitize the configuration files and remove all passwords etc.

Comment: @Cown
I have updated the thread which should highlight your requests. I didn't put in the full configurations for the sake of trying to keep an overview. Do let me know if it's not satisfying enough, tho.

Comment: @RoyT. On your links between L3-1 and L3-2, how come you don't use a normal trunked etherchannel? Does the 172.16.0.1 255.255.255.252 have any purpose?

Comment: It will be a lot easier if you would be able to show all the config from the L3-1 and L3-2 plus config from each Access Switch

Comment: You'll need to make up your mind whether you route or bridge between those switches. A layer-3 interface is a *router interface* and any VLAN on that interface isn't bridged to anywhere else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@RoyT. On your links between L3-1 and L3-2, how come you don't use a normal trunked etherchannel? Does the 172.16.0.1 255.255.255.252 have any purpose?

For instance, if you put this configuration on the interlink between L3-1 and L3-2:

```
interface Port-channel1
 switchport
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/19
 switchport
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
 channel-group 1 mode desirable
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/20
 switchport
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
 channel-group 1 mode desirable
!
```

Then everything will be able to communicate.

In order to do it:

```
(config)# int range gi2/0/19-20
(config-if)# no channel-group
(config-if)# switchport
(config-if)# switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
(config-if)# switchport mode trunk
(config-if)# int po1
(config-if)# no ip address
(config-if)# switchport
(config-if)# switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
(config-if)# switchport mode trunk
(config-if)# int range gi2/0/19-20
(config-if)# channel-group 1 mode desirable
(config-if)# end
# write memory
```

Comment: Hi @Cown - I think I already tried this, without success.. I will try again tho, right now I get the error that an interface with encapsulation set to "auto" can't be configured to trunk mode. I will try and set encapsulation 802.1q and try again.

Comment: @RoyT. Yeah i used the example on Cisco 6500 series, so no encapsulation needed.

Comment: @RoyT. edited to include encapsulation.

Comment: @RoyT. no problem :-)

Answer (score 3):

L3 EtherChannel and VLAN/Trunk concepts DO NOT work together.

In this scenario, you should use L2 EtherChannel between L3-1 and L3-2 switches.

Ensure that you create all L3 Int VLANs / L2 VLANs, and trunk them on this L2 EtherChannel between L3-1 and L3-2 switches.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly spanning tree is blocking the ports to communicate with each other...

Comment: Spanning tree is a layer-2 protocol. It does not cross a layer-3 boundary. You cannot use layer-2 concepts like VLANs or spanning tree on a layer-3 link. The accepted answer was to change the link to a layer-2 link.